# Refactor Object.keys(object).map to get the a nested array value. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'd like to refactor a block of code which basically has to map 2 levels to the data I want. The data I want is the value of body in a object that contains ['key'] that has array of objects .

My object looks as follows,

```
const object = {
    "array-one": [
        {
            id: 1,
            body: "need_help",
      
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            body: "no_help",

        },
    ],
}
```

and below is how I map to get the value of body

```
const getTheBodyValue = () => Object.keys(object).map(key => {

    object[key].map((elem) => {
        const { id, body } = elem;
        if (body === 'need_help') // do something
        if (body === 'no_help')  // do something
    });
});
```

is there a more simpler way to achieve the value of body in "array-one" & "array-two"?

Comment: why do you take an inner `map` without using the result? what are you doing inside the clauses?

Comment: @NinaScholz I need to access the value of body that is all. I can't access it without the inner map.

Comment: Don't use `map` to loop through things. Use `forEach` or a `for` loop. Use `map` to create a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flat the values from the object and take a single loop.

```
Object 
    .values(object)
    .flat()
    .forEach(({ id, body }) => {
        // your code
    })
```